# Auto-refresh calendar list / web part (SharePoint 2010)

Tags: calendar, refresh

How can you auto-refresh a SharePoint 2010 calendar list / web part, without needing to refresh the whole page? Tasks and other list types seem to have this option (under 'AJAX Options'), but not calendars.

Answer (score 2):

modify master page and add Java-script simple code to that refresh it every N seconds.

you can search with Google and using those JS codes.

this is helpful for those pages that contains these web parts >> like charts and calendar and etc. that we haven't those options.

after this answer i search here in this stack and found similar question and answer:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/27489/5170

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using content web part instead of modifying master page to store JS. But in other steps I agree with "saber tabatabaee yazdi".