# Refresh web part without refreshing page

Tags: web-part, jquery, updatepanel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Refreshing custom developed web part](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27484/refreshing-custom-developed-web-part)

I have a custom web part that displays items from a list. A user can select an item and edit the metadata on it. I want to refresh the web part after the user has edited an item. The only way I can do this now is if I call the location.reload() Javascript function. The issue is that it refreshes the entire page. I just want to refresh the web part, not the entire page.

Comment: Is this different than your previous question? Right now, I can't see a difference so I closed it since you were getting a bunch of pretty good answers on the other one. Let me know if you were trying to ask something different.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use Sharepoint Designer or VS Studio?
    In Sharepoint designer you can add an Asyn update button and that does work.
    Hope that helps

Comment: I used VS Studio.