# How do I update/refresh a web part using an AJAX Update panel every 5 or 10 minutes?

Tags: web-part, development, visual-studio, sharepoint-enterprise, asp.net

I have a news and announcement web part that I would liek to refresh every 5 or 10 minutes so users get the latest information. I have a bunch of asp controls within an update panel's contenttemplate. What code do I need to refresh or update the web part every 5 or 10 minutes?

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate
   <div>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <asp:Repeater ID="repAnnouncements" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <td style="padding-right:15px; padding-top:1px;">
                <asp:HyperLink ID="hypImageEditLink" runat="server">
                    <asp:Image ID="imgLink" runat="server" Width="150px" Height="110px" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Images")%>'/>
                </asp:HyperLink>
                <br/><br />
                <asp:HyperLink ID="hypTextEditLink" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Title")%>' CssClass="TitleStyle"/>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="ItemID" Value='<%#Eval("ID") %>' runat="server" />

            </td>
           </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
  </tr>
 </table>
   <asp:Label ID="test" runat="server" Visible="false" />
    </div>
    ></ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to update using the ASP.NET AJAX UpdatePanel, then just add a [Timer Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Check a similar question here - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27484/refreshing-custom-developed-web-part